# Issue with casting

Tags: scala, types, casting, subclass, covariant

```
    import scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance
    import scala.collection.immutable.Queue
    import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer


  abstract class Exp[+T:Manifest] { // constants/symbols (atomic)
    def tp: Manifest[T @uncheckedVariance] = manifest[T] //invariant position! but hey...
  }
  case class Sym[+T:Manifest](val id: Int) extends Exp[T] {
  }
  abstract class Def[+T] { // operations (composite)
    override final lazy val hashCode = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._hashCode(this.asInstanceOf[Product])
  }
  abstract class Stm
  case class TP[+T](sym: Sym[T], rhs: Def[T]) extends Stm

  abstract class Trial{
  }

  class M1() extends Trial{}
  class M2() extends Trial{}

  class N1() extends Def[M1]{}
  class N2() extends Def[M2]{}

  TP(Sym[M1]{4},new N1())
```

This gives the following error:

> scala>   TP(Sym[M1]{4},new N1()) java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> N1 cannot be cast to class scala.Product (N1 is in unnamed module of
> loader scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader
> @2098d37d; scala.Product is in unnamed module of loader 'bootstrap')
> at Def.hashCode$lzycompute(:13)   at
> Def.hashCode(:13)   at
> java.base/java.lang.Object.toString(Object.java:246)   at
> java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)   at
> java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:168)   at
> scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.addString(IterableOnce.scala:1194)
> at
> scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.addString$(IterableOnce.scala:1186)
> at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.addString(Iterator.scala:1279)
> at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.mkString(IterableOnce.scala:1136)
> at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.mkString$(IterableOnce.scala:1134)
> at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.mkString(Iterator.scala:1279)
> at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$._toString(ScalaRunTime.scala:159)   at
> TP.toString(:18)   at
> scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.inner$1(ScalaRunTime.scala:261)   at
> scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.stringOf(ScalaRunTime.scala:266)   at
> scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.replStringOf(ScalaRunTime.scala:274)   at
> .lzycompute(:8)   ... 28 elided

I was expecting an object of type TP[Trial], what happened? Since Sym and Def are covariant types. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: What does all of this have to do with the fact that `N1` and `N2` cannot be cast into `Product` by `this.asInstanceOf[Product]`? Make `N1` and `N2` into `case class`-es, then it runs without exceptions.
It all looks quite complicated, more complicated than the names of the involved entities suggest. Would you mind briefly describing what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, I really don't understand why N1 and N2 has to be case classes, Can you explain?

Comment: The documentation on [Product](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/Product.html) basically lists all the common implementations of that trait - those are, essentially, tuples and case classes. Since `N1` is clearly not a tuple, it probably should be a `case class` if it's supposed to not cause any `ClassCastException`s. What did you expect from that `Product` type cast?

Answer (score 1):

At Scastie it isn't reprodusible as https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tCD4HahgTqO4WTnlGcfWqQ but is reprodusible as https://scastie.scala-lang.org/L46PWLF2S5i4d1IGoT6UuQ

Locally I can reproduce `ClassCastException` only if I remove `lazy` for `Def#hashCode`.

Covariance is irrelevant.

In `this.asInstanceOf[Product]` you're trying to cast `Def`'s `this` to `Product`. When you create `new N1()` it is current `Def`'s `this`.

`new N1()` as a value of class `N1` cannot be cast to `Product` because `N1` doesn't extend `Product`.

In Scala by default classes do not extend `Product`, case classes do.

To fix `ClassCastException` it's enough to make `N1` a case class.